# Calculate storage space used by sql server sql_variant data type to store fixed length data types

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm trying to calculate the storage space used by [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) to store fixed length data types.

For my test I created a table with two columns:

```
  Key int identitiy(1,1) primary key
  Value sql_variant
```

I added one row with Value 1 of type [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) and I used DBCC PAGE to check the size of the row, that turned out being 21 bytes.

Using [Estimate the Size of a Clustered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085.aspx) I have:

```
  Null_bitmap = 3
  Fixed_Data_Size = 4 (Key column int)
  Variable_Data_Size = 2 + 2 + 4 (Value column with an int)

  Row_Size = 4 + 8 + 3 + 4 = 19 bytes
```

Why does the row take 21 bytes? What am I missing in my calculation?

I tried the same analysis with a table using an int column instead of the sql_variant and the used byte count reported by DBCC PAGE is 15, which match my calculation:

```
  Null_bitmap = 3
  Fixed_Data_Size = 8 (Key column int, Value column int)
  Variable_Data_Size = 0

  Row_Size = 4 + 8 + 3 = 15 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is the sql_variant metadata information.  From the BOL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx

*Each instance of a sql_variant column records the data value and the metadata information. This includes the base data type, maximum size, scale, precision, and collation.

For compatibility with other data types, the catalog objects, such as the DATALENGTH function, that report the length of sql_variant objects report the length of the data. The length of the metadata that is contained in a sql_variant object is not returned.*

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, I think the correct link you meant to reference is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071(v=sql.105).aspx (I googled the quote :))

Comment: Does this mean that for every sql_variant column I should consider an additional 2 bytes for the metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You missed part 7.

> 7 . Calculate the number of rows per page (8096 free bytes per page):
>
> Rows_Per_Page = 8096 / (Row_Size + 2)
>
> Because rows do not span pages, the number of rows per page should be
>   rounded down to the nearest whole row. The value 2 in the formula is
>   for the row's entry in the slot array of the page.

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm concerned about the space used by the row data. That point is about the space used by the page, in particular to the slot array that is present at the bottom of every data page (http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/). I edited the post adding also the test I made with a fixed length column instead of the sql_variant and the calculation works, so I am clearly missing something but I cannot figure out what.